# Error returned by saving with variable name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a macro that extracts data from a spreadsheet, creates a new spreadsheet & pastes the data, then saves the new spreadsheet into the same file location as the original location. It's used by colleagues at work who often open files from SharePoint.

The method for saving before today was the following line. All the variables are appropriately declared earlier in the macro.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=strOriginFolder & "\" & strNewDate & " MA-OI timeline", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
```

This works fine, but some colleagues are opening files from a folder within a dozen folders, and when saving the new spreadsheet they run out of string characters for the save name & location. I've tried to overcome this issue with the following code:

```
Dim strFileName As String * 1024
strFileName = strOriginFolder & "\" & strNewDate & " MA-OI timeline"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFileName, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
```

I read recently that you can bypass the string limit by declaring it like I have there, so I assumed making the small change I made would be ok. When I try to run it, I get run-time error 1004: Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed.

When I've tried searching for solutions, they mostly mention the reserved characters such as ':' and '', which are included in 'strOriginFolder', but the variable is used in my original code and it works fine.

Comment: There is effectively a limit to the total path length (400 for SP online, 260 for server SP?) you can use when saving a file.  You mention your users open files from SharePoint but it's not clear if that's where your code is saving them to? You're using the HTTP path, or a mapped drive/folder?

Comment: @TimWilliams I didn't know there was a limit to path length, so thank you! Some users will be using a mapped folder, but the vast majority would open their original file through a HTTP path, then open via desktop app. The string strOriginFolder is definitely a HTTP path.

Comment: Path limits are often a big headache - people like to use a full sentence as a file/folder name...